# Conversion of XML file - changing attribute values into attributes and values into attribute values

Tags: xml, attributes, tags, converters

Is there a way to make "switches" in XML, as I explained in title changing attribute values into attributes of tag, and values into values of attributes of a tag.
Example:

```
<attribute name="Krantyp">value</attribute>
<attribute name="Beschreibung">value2</attribute>
```

to turn into something like this:

```
<attribute Krantyp="value" Beschreibung="value2"/>
```

so, in this example, tag is "attribute", value of attribute name has to become attribute (name not exists anymore!), here "Krantyp" becomes new attribute. Value of tag "value" becomes value of new attribute "Krantyp" and so on.

Is this even possible? If it is, what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: XSLT is made for such tasks.

Comment: It's very confusing to have elements named `attribute`, and if you're going to do it, it would help greatly if your question was written to carefully distinguish between XML attributes on the one hand, and XML elements named `attribute` on the other.

Answer (score 2):

Check it out.

**Input XML**

```
<root>
    <attribute name="Krantyp">value</attribute>
    <attribute name="Beschreibung">value2</attribute>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <attribute>
                <xsl:for-each select="attribute">
                    <xsl:attribute name="{@name}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<root>
  <attribute Krantyp="value" Beschreibung="value2"/>
</root>
```